# Start single Serenity scenario from command line

Tags: java, testing, junit, serenity-js

My team received ownership of a webapp. Tests are written with junit suites and serenity. Good things, there a good test coverage. Problem come when you need to run that single test/scenario that is still failing and you need to wait >30min to run everything.

**How can I run a single scenario of this suite using mvn command line?**

From code editor, it's hard to start single scenario as both suite and test classes contains important initialization code.
I've also tried argument '-Dtest=T1Test#T1Scenario1' without success.

Code snipplet:

```
   @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
            UserConfigASuite.class,
            UserConfigBSuite.class,
            UserConfigCSuite.class
    })
    public class AllTestSuite {
    }

    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
        T1Test.class,
        T2Test.class,
        //... Lots of other tests
    })public class UserConfigASuite {
      @BeforeClass
      public static void beforeClass() {
          //Required init code
      }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        //Cleanup after test suite
      }
    }

    @RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
    public class T1Test {

      @Test
      @Title("T1: scenario 1")
      public void T1Scenario1() {

      } 

      //... Lots of other scenarios
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirm first that your using supported surefire and junit version. For more details refer https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

In case your using maven failsafe plugin then the syntax will vary little bit. Something like this

`mvn -Dit.test=ITCircle#test* verify`

Refer https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html for more details.

Comment: Turn out it was a silly question. Using failsafe, _-Dit.test_ was the right parameter. Thx.