# Serenity Junit - How can I execute a specified single test via mvn command with serenity

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am a beginner with Serenity Junit. I am trying to clarify if there is any way to execute a single test of a specified test class via `mvn` command-line? I also tried with `mvn clean verify -Dtest="com.studentapp.junit.studentsinfo.StudentsCRUDTest"` but all of my tests were executed instead of only the tests in **StudentsCRUDTest** class.

As you see in my capture, there is only one test in my `StudentsCRUDTest` class
[image]

Your help to clarify my concern would be extremely appreciated from my indeed.
Thanks

Comment: mvn test -Dtest=StudentsCRUDTest base on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven

Comment: Thank you very much for your information @MaroineMlis. I post my comment as another answer below because I am not able to attach my capture Images to the comment session. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you for your link also @KristofNeirynck. Your link is also really informative to me, but the comment session is not allowed to tag 2 usernames in the same comment hihi :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run by tag:

```
$ mvn clean verify -Dtags="your-tag"
```

refer: https://johnfergusonsmart.com/running-serenity-bdd-tests-with-tags/

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @lucasnguyen17. I was able to execute a single test by tag successfully. In my question, I would like to find some way to execute my single test via command line for debugging or investigating purposes, I don't want to add a tag (ex: `development:in-progress`) whenever I would like to re-run or debug my single test.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your information @MaroineMlis and @Kristof Neirynck, I found the root cause from your suggested links. It works like a charm when I update the maven-surefire plugins configuration in my POM as below:
[image: My POM file before updating]

[image: My POM file after updating]

Comment: Serenity bdd uses failsafe plugin, not surefire, so I guess you can run the test but no serenity report.

Comment: Serenity report is also generated normally with my following command @lucasnguyen17`mvn clean test -Dtest=com.studentapp.junit.createStudent.CreateStudentTest serenity:aggregate`

Comment: @lucasnguyen17, Thank you for your information. I found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377534/start-single-serenity-scenario-from-command-line.

When using failsafe, we need to use `mvn verify -Dit.test=className#testMethodName` instead of `mvn test -Dtest=className#testMethodName` as maven surefire